# How to merge objects based on their key values?

Tags: javascript, object

I have this array of objects with some duplicate objects and some matching name value.

```
const users = [
    {name: 'john', city: 'london', age: '20'},
    {name: 'john', city: 'london', age: '25'},
    {name: 'john', city: 'london', age: '20'},
    {name: 'sam', city: 'london', age: '30'}
]
```

I am trying to get the rid out of duplicate objects first and then merge objects with similar name value like this.

Desired Array:

```
const newUsers = [
    {name: 'john', city: 'london', age: [20,25]},
    {name: 'sam', city: 'london', age: [30]}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to transform your array of objects into an ES6 [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). The map can contain the name as the key and the object as the value. The value of the object, however, has an `age` property which is an accumulated [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of all `age` values. As this is a set it will keep all unique `age` values from objects with the same `name` property. You can then wrap the Map returned by `.reduce()` in a call to [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), which will allow you to convert the map to an array. The mapping function provided to `Array.from()` can convert each set to an array of values.

See example below:

```js
const arr = [{name: 'john', city: 'london', age: '20'}, {name: 'john', city: 'london', age: '25'}, {name: 'john', city: 'london', age: '20'}, {name: 'sam', city: 'london', age: '30'}];

const res = Array.from(arr.reduce((m, o) => {
  const c = m.get(o.name);
  return m.set(o.name, {...o, age: (c && c.age || new Set).add(+o.age)});
}, new Map).values(), v => ({...v, age: [...v.age]}));

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; } /* ignore */
```

To help break the above down here is what each part is responsible for:

1. `arr.reduce((m, o) => {...}, new Map)` - The reduce method here is used to loop over each object in the array `arr`. For each object, it calls the callback function. The value of `o` is the current iterated object, and the value of `m` is the accumulator. The accumulator represents the value the callback returned on its previous iteration. When the callback is first called there have been no previous iterations, so the accumulator takes the default value of `new Map` specified as the second argument in `.reduce()` after the callback. A `Map` in JavaScript is very similar to an object `{}`. It keeps key-value pairs just like an object does, where is key must be unique (repeating a key overwrites the old key-value pair).
2. `const c = m.get(o.name);` - This piece of code is responsible for grabbing the value stored at the current object's `name` property in the `Map`. If a value exists, it will be an object literal storing the key and values for the object with that `name`. However, unlike the original object from the array, it's `age` property will be a `Set` which will contain all ages for objects with that particular name (how this is done is revealed in step 3). We use a `Set` here as it doesn't allow for duplicates, so if the same age is added, then it won't double up on it. If the key of `o.name` doesn't exist yet in the map, `c` will be `undefined`.
3. `return m.set(o.name, {...o, age: (c && c.age || new Set).add(+o.age)});` - This returns an updated version of the Map, to be used in the next iteration of the reduce callback. `m.set()` takes two values. A key and a value (it is similar to performing `obj[key] = value` except that it returns the updated object rather than the value). The key, in this case, is `o.name`, which is the value of the object's `name` property. The value here is a newly created object literal. The new object literal contains all the properties of the current iterated object `o` (this is done by spreading all the keys and values into the new object literal using `...o` - see [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for more details). It also overwrites the `age` property from the current iterated object to be a new `Set` which contains the current iterated objects `age` value. This is done by this section `c && c.age || new Set`. Here, we check if `c` is defined (ie `c` holds an object), and if it is (`&&`), use the Set we previously defined (`c.age`). If `c` is not defined (`||`), then create a new empty set (`new Set()`). As this will always result in a `Set` we can safely use `.add(+o.age)` on it to add the current iterated object's age to the set.
4. `.values()` - Once reduce() has iterated over all the objects in `arr`, it returns the final value of the accumulated map `m`. As the Map's values stores all our desired objects, we can use `.values()` to get an iterator which will iterate over all the Map's values for us. In our case, we don't want an iterator but rather we want an array (see step 5).
5. `Array.from(arr.reduce(...), v => ({...v, age: [...v.age]}))` - Array.from() can take an iterator and convert it into an array for us. For each value it iterates on, it will call the callback function provided as the second argument. The return value of the callback is what is used as the current element in the array produced by `Array.from()`. In our case, the callback accepts a given value (from our map - so `v` is an object), and returns a new object literal. This object contains all the properties of the current object as its contents is spread into the new object literal `...v`. As our object still contains a `Set`, we can set the `age` property to be an array, by spreading the set into an array (`[...v.age]`).

If you can support new features introduced in ECMAScript 2020 such as the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) (`??`) and [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (`?.`) then you can remove the need for the temporary `c` variable:

```js
const arr = [ {name: 'john', city: 'london', age: '20'}, {name: 'john', city: 'london', age: '25'}, {name: 'john', city: 'london', age: '20'}, {name: 'sam', city: 'london', age: '30'} ];

const res = Array.from(
  arr.reduce((m, o) =>
    m.set(o.name, {...o, age: (m.get(o.name)?.age ?? new Set).add(+o.age)}) , new Map).values(), 
  v => ({...v, age: [...v.age]})
);

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; } /* ignore */
```

Comment: u have used OR operator as if condition to create a new Set in (c && c.age || new Set). If thats true ... its a new thing i never came across yet.

Comment: The `||` operator actually returns a value. The `||` operator returns the first [_truthy_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value it comes across (if it finds no truthy values it returns the last operand). So, for example, if you have `false || 0 || "a"`, it would return `"a"` because a non-empty string is considered truthy (whereas `false` and `0` are [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values). So, if `c && c.age` results in a falsy value, the || will return a `new Set` (as no other operands are truthy, it will return the last operand).

Comment: I was using OR operator most of the time in if condition so i had this illusion that it return a Boolean.  thx for clearing the air again. You are gr8

Comment: @illiterate.farmer no worries :). I also first thought that `||` returned a boolean, but then, later on, learnt it returned one of its operands.

Comment: @illiterate.farmer if your questions receive a negative score/get closed frequently then you're at risk of being banned. See here for details: https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans When asking questions, make sure you clearly state what you've tried (it shows that you've put some effort into solving the problem so people will be less likely to dv you). Also, if possible, link some similar related questions which you tried but didn't seem to solve your issue (this helps show others you did research).

Comment: @illiterate.farmer Here is how you can do your regex question: https://jsfiddle.net/d67eyrLt/1/

Comment: thx it worked. I am going to create a new account now and follow these instructions closely. BTW i m making a web for corona to help the governments make lock-down successful

Comment: @illiterate.farmer oh ok, nice. Just a warning though, I don't think creating a new account  will work [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998) - See top answer and look for the "Can I simply create a new account?" section.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) as shown below:

```js
const users = [
   {name: 'john', city: 'london', age: '20'},
   {name: 'john', city: 'london', age: '25'},
   {name: 'john', city: 'london', age: '20'},
   {name: 'sam', city: 'london', age: '30'}
];        
    
uniqueUsers = [];
users.forEach(user => {
  const existingUser = uniqueUsers.find(u => u.name == user.name && u.city == user.city); 
  if (existingUser) {
    if (!existingUser.age.includes(Number(user.age))) {
      existingUser.age.push(Number(user.age));
    }
  } else {
    user.age = [Number(user.age)];
    uniqueUsers.push(user);
  }
});    
console.log(uniqueUsers);
```